# DateTime.Parse always throws exception in a specific culture

Tags: c#, .net

I have some old log files I have to parse - apparently the date time was saved like:
18/12/2012 11:09:39 p.m. - All my attempts to parse these have failed.
I am completely lost on this - Any help or direction would be great!

```
 CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo( "es-MX" , true );
        string date = "18/12/2012 11:09:39 p.m.";

        DateTime dt = new DateTime( 2012 , 12 , 18 , 11 , 9 , 39 ).AddHours( 12 );

        this.richTextBox1.Text += date + Environment.NewLine;
        this.richTextBox1.Text += dt.ToString( cultureInfo ) + Environment.NewLine;
        this.richTextBox1.Text += dt.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;

        foreach ( var item in richTextBox1.Lines )
        {
            try
            {
               DateTime d=  DateTime.Parse( item );
               this.richTextBox1.Text += d.ToString() + Environment.NewLine ;

            }
            catch ( Exception ee)
            {
                this.richTextBox1.Text += ee.Message + Environment.NewLine ;

            }
        }
```

Comment: **ALWAYS**...well... in a specific culture. +1

Comment: You're catching the exception, right?  What is it?

Comment: 50% of the time, my code works 100% of the time.

Comment: @Brian for a few seconds after reading your comment, I though it was Op's comment...  wow..

Comment: @Brian Extra lolz assuming your last name is Fontana.

Comment: 'erm DateTime.Parse(item,cultureInfo) maybe..

Comment: The exception is: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some dates are correct in the log file(s) some have the odd formatting that end in p. m. or p.m..
All methods above seem to fail - and yes I tried them all :(
This was my hack/fix for the problem:

```
     CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo( "es-MX" , true );
     Date = DateTime.Parse( date.Replace( "p. m." , "PM" ).Replace( "p.m." , "PM" ).Replace( "." , "" ).ToUpper() , cultureInfo );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using DateTime.TryParseExact().  Here's an example that I ran in LINQPad.

```
void Main()
{
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo( "es-MX" , true );
    string date = "18/12/2012 11:09:39 p.m.";

    DateTime dt = new DateTime( 2012 , 12 , 18 , 11 , 9 , 39 ).AddHours( 12 );

    DateTime d;
    string[] styles = {"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"}; // This doesn't have to be an array - could be string
    DateTime.TryParseExact(date, styles, cultureInfo, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out d);

    d.Dump();
}
```

Comment: This fails as well - no different than the code I posted.... d = {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM} - I guess the tryparse is failing...

Comment: @BillyDvd Just copy, pasted and ran in LINQPad and it ran correctly.  Try doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using your cultureInfo variable as the second parameter of Parse.  This will use the culture as the format provider.

```
DateTime d =  DateTime.Parse( item, cultureInfo );
```

Comment: @Nicholas - unfortunately I didn't expand the comments under the original question before submitting.  Tony Hopkinson posted it before both of us.

Comment: Adding this gives the exception: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 20.

Comment: Are you still just parsing that example or are you trying to parse the log files you are working on?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not specifying the culture to use in your call to Parse(). Your invocation uses the current thread's CurrentCulture property:

```
DateTime d=  DateTime.Parse( item );
```

The magic incantation you need is something like:

```
DateTime instance = DateTime.Parse( text , CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-MX") ) ;
```

Your other alternative is to change the current thread's culture:

```
CultureInfo mexico = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo( "es-MX" );
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = mexico;
```

before you call `DateTime.Parse()`. Do that at startup and you should be good to go (so long as working in Mexican spanish is good for your purposes. Note that changing the current culture won't change how things are displayed: that's the responsibility of the thread's CurrentUICulture property.

Comment: Still produces the exception: 
The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 20.

Comment: @BillyDvd, have you check what the actual characters are in the failing string? offset +20 in your sample string is the lower-case 'p' in `p.m.`. I'm willing to be that you've got bad data somewhere. Do you have multiple spaces embedded in the string? You might want to relax the whitespace handling with one of the `Parse()` overloads that supports specifying `DateTimeStyles`.